# Mistakenly ran chmod 644 /usr/* Any way to recover my installation?

Tags: macos, shell

I ran `chmod 644 /usr/*` on my installation of Mac OSX 10.6.

Now, everything is not working, from `chmod` to every other command. Obviously those commands are in `/usr/bin`, and I do not have execute permissions for `chmod` to give myself execute permissions.

Comment: What do you mean? `chmod` is in `/bin/`?

Comment: Is your machine still running- i.e., is Finder up? You can make mode changes in Finder too. If not, where does your boot process fail?

Comment: @PooriaAzimi mistake, i intended to say the sudo cmd is in /bin

Answer (score 6):

## The Typical Method

OSX has the built-in application Disk Utility to fix issues like this. Follow Apple's guide for [troubleshooting permissions issues in Mac OS X](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2963), and learn [about Disk Utility's Repair Disk Permissions feature](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1452).

> For Mac OS X 10.2 or later, open Disk Utility (`/Applications/Utilities/`). Select your Mac OS X startup volume in the column on the left of the Disk Utility window, then click the First Aid tab. Click the Repair Disk Permissions button.

---

## The Extreme Cases Methods

### Method 1

1. Download [AppleJack](http://sourceforge.net/projects/applejack/files/latest/download)
2. Mount the AppleJack disk image, and run the `AppleJack.pkg` installer
3. Now we will run AppleJack:

   1. Restart your computer
   2. When the "bong" sounds, hold down the <kbd>⌘</kbd> and <kbd>s</kbd> keys until you get lots of text appearing on a black screen. You are now in single user mode.
   3. Type `applejack auto restart` at the prompt and hit <kbd>return</kbd>

### Method 2 (with help from [macstrategy.com](http://www.macstrategy.com/article.php?7))

1. Find someone with an 10.6.* OSX install disc (or burn/write your own)
2. Boot your Mac from the disc (do one of the following):

   1. Insert your install disc, restart your computer and hold down the <kbd>c</kbd> key (recommended).
   2. Insert your install disc, go to `Apple menu > System Preferences > Startup Disk` and select the install disc, then restart your computer.
   3. Insert your install disc, restart your computer and hold down the <kbd>alt</kbd> (option) key, select the install disc, click the up or right arrow.
3. Select your required language.
4. Don't install Mac OS X but instead go to the Utilities menu and select `Disk Utility`.
5. Select the disk icon in the top left of the drive you want to repair permissions on e.g. `Macintosh HD`.
6. Click on the `First Aid` tab at the top.
7. Click on the `Repair Disk Permissions` button.
8. When this has finished quit the Disk Utility application and restart your computer normally.

Comment: The disk utility is not running :(

Comment: I just updated my answer @karthik-ramasamy

Comment: @emb1995 What is AppleJack?

Comment: @Luke From their SF site: AppleJack is a user friendly troubleshooting assistant for Mac OS X. With AppleJack you can troubleshoot a computer even if you can`t load the GUI, or don`t have a startup CD handy. AppleJack runs in Single User Mode and is menu-based for ease of use

Comment: @emb1995 Looks interesting... Downloading

Answer (score 2):

Well, most of the directories and files have 755 as the default so I would start there to allow you to execute common utilities. You can then later figure out if you want to tighten security.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr
```

---

[This page](http://troysunix.blogspot.se/2010/10/fix-broken-chmod-or-how-to-chmod-chmod.html) has a variety of ideas, depending on what you have access to. Example, if you have execute permissions on `cp`, `mv` and `cat` you could use the following sequence of commands to "copy" permissions from another file (in this example `/bin/ls`).

```
/bin/cp /bin/ls /tmp/chmod
/bin/cat /bin/chmod > /tmp/chmod
/bin/mv /tmp/chmod /bin/chmod
```

Notes: The first commands copies a file (including permissions). The second command copies the contents of chmod to the new file (does not overwrite permissions). The last command overwrites the original chmod file.

Comment: The main problem I have is I dont have execute permission for sudo,cp  commands.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to run in Superuser mode, or run the CD

## Superuser Mode

1. Turn off the Mac
2. Hold <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> as you press Power
3. When it starts, you'll be presented with a ROOT prompt. Mount the file system (as shows in the instructions when you start), then add your Execute permission

## Run from the CD (recommended)

1. Insert the Mac OSX DVD and shutdown the Mac
2. Press and hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key as you turn on the Mac
3. Select the `Mac OSX Install DVD` option
4. Select your language and click Next
5. Select `Tools`->`Disk Utility`
6. Select your hard drive partition from the left side
7. On the First Aid tab, click `Repair Disk Permissions` and wait

Once either of these are done, reboot your Mac

Comment: Actually, it is not recommended to repair permissions from the DVD. [Apple recommends](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1452) repairing while started up from a Mac OS X volume that contains Mac OS X. Running Disk Utility while started from the Mac OS X volume ensures that the changes made by software updates are preserved.

Comment: @emb1995 It eliminates issues where the current installation won't run the repair properly. You can always run it again inside your installation

Comment: I tried your Superuser Mode solution and set the right permissions for the /usr and everything got fixed now except terminal, which was showing "could not determine audit condition" error and deleting /usr/bin/login file fixed that problem.

Comment: Thanks Luke and everybody for helping me out on this and saving me a work day :)

Comment: @KarthikRamasamy If it worked, remember to select it as the answer, unless another answer worked better for you